# is this test right: if(obj1.type == obj2.type == 1)?

Tags: c#, objective-c, c

is this test right: `if(obj1.type == obj2.type == 1)` and what does it do actually? I'm wondering if this imply some `&&` in the condition or not.

Comment: What language are you interested in? You've tagged the question with three different ones. As for whether it's "right" - that depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `obj1.type == obj2.type == 1` == `(obj1.type == obj2.type) == 1` and comparison with `1` latter is sense-less

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C and Objective-C, groups of `==` operators are evaluated left-to-right, and produce a zero or a one result. Because of this, your expression is the same as

```
 if(obj1.type == obj2.type)
```

In C# this produces an error, because `==` operator cannot be applied to operands of type `bool` and `int`.

If you would like to say "if both `obj1.type` and `obj2.type` equal `1`", you need to use two separate `==` conditions, and put a logical "AND" operator between them:

```
if(obj1.type == 1 && obj2.type == 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using above test condition, you can change it into:

```
    if((obj1.type == obj2.type) && (obj2.type== 1))
```

or you can try changing it to::

```
    if((obj1.type == 1) && (obj2.type== 1))
```

For difference between both:

```
&& operator
```

&& operates on boolean operands only. It evaluates its first operand. If the result is false, it returns false. Otherwise, it evaluates and returns the results of the second operand. Note that, if evaluating the second operand would hypothetically have no side effects, the results are identical to the logical conjunction performed by the & operator. This is an example of Short Circuit Evaluation.

```
== Operator
```

For arguments of value type, the operator == returns true, if its operands have the same value, false otherwise. For the string type, it returns true, if the strings' character sequences match. For other reference types (types derived from System.Object), however, a == b returns true only if a and b reference the same object.

Comment: @NicolasManzini I feel you might try your self first.

Comment: @NicolasManzini I think `if((obj1.type == obj2.type) && (obj2.type== 1))` is complex essay is `if((obj1.type == 1) && (obj2.type== 1))`

Comment: how its not correct,try compiling it,if all of the three values are same then only the loop will get executed..

Comment: that would be the classical way to test both

Comment: @NicolasManzini read comment I posted. it should be  `A == C && B == C`

Comment: *`&& operates on boolean operands only.`*  is wrong.. also codify programming terms in text.

Answer (score 1):

If obj1 and obj2 are two objects of your custom class which has a member named "type" then in that case above statement will give you following error:

Operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

It gives this error because when it evaluates `(obj1.type==obj2.type)` it returns in a bool value (true/false) which cannot be compared with an integer value using `==` operator.

If you want to compare the types of two objects then in that case your code is not correct. C# object class doesn't have any property or member like type. It has a method named GetType() which you can use as follows for comparing the type of two objects.

```
  if(obj1.GetType() == obj2.GetType())
```

Comment: @Charles: Thanks! for edit. It increased the readability of the post.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a test question.

Well for one it won't compile in c# because obj1.type == obj2.type evaluates first and then the statement tries to compare that Boolean result to an int.

I can't speak to objective c.

In c it will compile and probably fail always because again the first comparison is done and either returns false (0) or true (anything but 0).  The odds of == returning 1 for true are probably %0 but could be possible %100 depending on the compiler because that detail is left to the vendor.  The first comparison might return 0xFFFFFFFF or -12 for true.  Also what the test is trying to do I assume is functionally equivalent to just

```
if (obj1.value == obj2.value)
```

and then bizarrely introduces a second redundant and faulty check against "true" again that the "if" statement would do on it's own.